# Artifactory upgrade fail, postgres 9.5 -> 9.6 upgrade instructions needed

Tags: upgrade, artifactory

I had planned an upgrade of artifactory from 6.7.5 to 6.8.1.  As part of the upgrade I checked jfrog's repo on github and it looks like they have a new recommended nginx and postgres version.

The current docker-compose is using postgres 9.5 and the new default version if 9.6.  Simply pulling down postgres 9.6 however does not do an inplace upgrade.

> FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server DETAIL:  The data
>   directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.5, which is not
>   compatible with this version 9.6.11.

The upgrade instructions do not mention anything about how to do the upgrade.

Comment: Seems like the problem is with the Database upgrade. Try upgrading the database first, and look on the Postgres upgrade documentations.

Comment: @gba I think that's my question. Can I just do a standard postgres upgrade according to their upgrade notes or do I need to go through some sort of jfrog procedure to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

The examples provided in github (https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-docker-examples) are just examples.
Using them in production could cause issues and backwards compatibility is not guaranteed.

To get over the PostgreSQL matter when upgrading, I would suggest:

1. $ docker-compose -f yml-file-name.yml stop
2. edit the yml-file-name.yml and change the docker.bintray.io/postgres:9.6.11 to docker.bintray.io/postgres:9.5.2
3. $ docker-compose -f yml-file-name.yml up -d

Artifactory should be upgraded after following this, however it will keep using the previous version of the PostgreSQL DB

Comment: Thanks.  I had already fallen back to the previous version and we're up and running.  However I'm assuming that I need to ugprade my postgress at some point.  I was hoping that jfrog provided the instructions on how to do the upgrade for their tool.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to upgrade database using following approach:

1. Dump all database to an SQL script using old database image; store it in a volume for future import:

```
# Override PostgreSQL image used to export using old binaries
printf "version: '2.1'\nservices:\n  postgresql:\n    image: docker.bintray.io/postgres:9.5.2\n" > image_override.yml
started_container=$(docker-compose -f artifactory-pro.yml -f image_override.yml run -d -v sql_dump_volume:/tmp/dump --no-deps postgresql)

# Dump database to a text file in a volume (to make it available for import)
docker exec "${started_container}" bash -c "until pg_isready -q; do sleep 1; done"
docker exec "${started_container}" bash -c "pg_dumpall --clean --if-exists --username=\${POSTGRES_USER} > /tmp/dump/dump.sql"
docker stop "${started_container}"
docker rm --force "${started_container}"
```

2. Back up old database directory and prepare a new one:

```
mv -fv /data/postgresql /data/postgresql.old
mkdir -p /data/postgresql
chown --reference=/data/postgresql.old /data/postgresql
chmod --reference=/data/postgresql.old /data/postgresql
```

3. Run a new database image with mounting dump script from step 1. It processes SQL scripts upon startup when setting up a new database, provided it's started as `postgres something`. We just don't need to leave the server running afterwards, so I provided `--version` to make entrypoint execute, import the data and quit:

```
docker-compose -f artifactory-pro.yml run --rm --no-deps -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=root -v sql_dump_volume:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d postgresql postgres --version
```

After all this is done, I was able to start Artifactory normally with `docker-compose -f artifactory-pro.yml up -d` and it started up normally, applying rest of schema and file upgrade procedure as usual.

I have also prepared [a script](https://github.com/raspy/artifactory-docker-examples/blob/a3c27d7cf496776aebee544b45e335ceebec859f/docker-compose/artifactory/upgrade-database.sh) that basically does the above steps along with some additional checks and cleanup. Feel free to use if you find it useful.